# Baixar dependências do Laravel via Composer no EC2 da AWS

Tags: php, laravel, composer, amazon-aws

Fiz o clone de um projeto Laravel em um servidor linux EC2 e quando vou baixar as dependências via composer ele da o erro

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
```

O projeto é com o Laravel 5.7 na versão 7.3 do PHP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é um erro, é só um aviso... Você não deve rodar o composer como root, mas se quiser pode.

Comment: Na verdade o erro em si é a extensão mbstring que está faltando

Comment: rode o comando `sudo yum install php-mbstring` para instalar

Comment: Aqui estão listadas as dependencias do laravel, você precisa instalar algumas extensões do php para funcionar corretamente https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/#installation

Comment: @sant0will deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que está retornando na verdade no console é a extensão `mbstring` que está faltando. Para realizar a instalação de uma projeto `laravel` são necessários alguns [pré-requisitos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/#installation) no servidor.

No seu caso como está faltando apenas a extensão mbstring e está utilizando um derivado RedHat, basta você rodar o comando:

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```